# How to download images using wget from a txt file that contains links

Tags: wget

I can download images using wget if I download from a website. But I have several links and I have saved them in a text file.

For example:

```
wget -r -A.jpg -np www.fragrancenet.com
```

There are so many pictures on this website. I have saved the links for the particular pictures I want:

```
www.fragrancenet.com/images1

www.fragrancenet.com/images2

www.fragrancenet.com/images3
```

The links are saved in a text file named `images.txt` in my computer.
How can I download the links in the `images.txt` text file using wget?

Answer (score 5):

Use this command:

```
wget -i images.txt
```

or

```
wget --input-file=images.txt
```

It will save the images in your current directory.