# wget ftp with credentials for a list of files

Tags: ftp, wget, syntax

[This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/499484/14596) isn't quite what I need.
Is there a way to do something like this

```
wget ftp://myname:longpassword@someipddress/images/ -i file_list.txt
```

I want to use the same credentials and look in the same ftp directory and download files based upon a list of them in a file.
I would prefer to have a simple list like this:

```
ABC.jpg
DEF.jpg
QRS.tif
FOL.dbf
```

rather than the complete `ftp://myname:longpassword@someipddress/images/` in each file asked for.

Is that possible? If so what would be the syntax?

**update:**  I accepted an answer here because it did answer my question, but anyone with an appropriate windows answer I would upvote at least also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux, try this:

```
xargs -i wget 'ftp://myname:longpassword@someipddress/images/{}' < file_list.txt
```

Comment: I am not, but I can be for this. Thank you.

Comment: this looks cool but seems to be the same as specifying the files in a file complete with adreses - at least i can still see its logging in for each file on the row ... (and creating and removing the .listing, just to find out i already have the file :). Somehow some fiiles arent downloaded when i ask for /* - there is several thousands of them - so i thought specifying them would help, logging in for each file sounds crazy :)